# Getting enumdropdownlist selected item/value in jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a enumdropdownlistfor that I want to get the selected value in jQuery. I can invoke the onchange for the enumdropdownlist but then how do I get the selected value from it?

Question 2 - is there a way to give each value an id and then get that id to pass to my controller in a post? Each value is an enumeration so do I need to pass back an id or a string? Not sure here.

Here is my code.

```js
$('#SpaceType').change(function () {
    var selectedValue = //$(this).find(':checked').attr('id');
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    $.post(url, { ID: id, SpaceType: spaceTypeId }, function(data) {
            // do something with the returned value e.g. display a message?
            //        // for example - if(data) { // OK } else { // Oops }
            //alert("success");
            $("#successmessage").show().delay(5000).fadeOut();
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert("error");
        });
});
```

```html
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Listing.SpaceType, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "SpaceType", data_id=@Model.YogaSpaceId, data_url=@Url.Action("UpdateSpaceType", "ManageSpaces" ) })
```

Comment: Its just `var selectedValue = $(this).val();` And you don't need an id